# SignalR SQL Server Scaleout Users Allocation

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client, signalr-backplane, signalr-2

I have implemented signalR Scaleout using SQL Server as shown here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server

So, I have Server 1 and Server 2.

What I would like to know, since I haven't been able to find a clear answer, is what happens to users connected to Server 1 when Server 1 goes down.

Do those users connect to Server 2 automatically by signalR or do they completely disconnect from everything?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: I tried using SignalR Groups but Client seems to disconnect from everything